# Distribution of the combination of square and the product of Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, distribution-theory

What is the distribution of the following expression?
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i^2  + \sum_{i \neq j; i,j=1}^n b_{ij} x_i x_j
$$
where $x_i$ for $i$ in the range from 1 to $n$ are i.i.d. samples from $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$,  $a_i$, and $b_{ij}$ are real constants.

Comment: If $n=2$ does that mean $a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2+b_{12}x_1x_2$ or $a_1x_1^2+a_2x_2^2+b_{12}x_1x_2+b_{21}x_2x_1$?

Comment: @Henry : If n=2, then $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i^2  + \sum_{i \neq j; i,j=1}^n b_{ij} x_i x_j = a_1 x_1^2 + a_2 x_2^2 + b_{12} x_1 x_2 + b_{21} x_2 x_1$$

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a quadratic form $x^\top Mx$, where $x\sim \mathcal N(0,I_n)$ and $M$ is symmetric.

If $M$ is an idempotent matrix of rank $m$ then [see this link](https://www2.econ.iastate.edu/classes/econ671/hallam/documents/QUAD_NORM.pdf)
$$x^\top Mx\sim\chi^2(\text{tr}(M))$$
However, if $M$ is not idempotent, it is not a well-known distribution. For further properties of this quadratic form, see [Variance of quadratic form for multivariate normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427332/variance-of-quadratic-form-for-multivariate-normal-distribution).

Comment: What can we say about the distribution if $M$ is a square matrix?

Comment: $M$ should always be a square matrix.

Comment: yes, it should always be a square matrix but in our case, it is not symmetric.

Comment: @Bisham: With  $m_{ij}=a_i$ when $i=j$ and $m_{ij}=\frac12(b_{ij}+b_{ji})$ when $i \not = j$, it will be symmetric